# what does "whiplash moment" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, attributive-nouns

I'm currently reading a New York Times article about the relationship change between the U.S. and Russia after the election of Mr. Trump. I came across the following: “We are in a whiplash moment right now, and I think it is unprecedented in several respects.” 
I can't quite grasp the meaning of the "whiplash moment."

I looked up the dictionary for "whiplash," but still can't make the meaning out of that noun being used as an adjective modifying the noun "moment."

I searched the web and found one explaining the "whiplash moment" as "a moment that gives your head a big old snap!" 
(http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/whiplash-moment.2108010/)

Still it is still vague for me. Can somebody explain this phrase with the relation with the context?

Comment: A clarification: in “a whiplash moment”, not one of those three words is an adjective.  *Whiplash* is a noun just like *moment* is, while *a* is an article. You can tell the difference because it would be ungrammatical to say that ”a moment **is** whiplash”. It is not, so you cannot say that. Therefore *whiplash* is a noun used attributively, not an adjective. This is a common error in analysis. It is also an error in logic: just because a chimpanzee is an ape does not mean that all apes are chimpanzees, which is what you have done here. Adjectives are noun modifiers, but hardly the only ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it seems they're going off the definition of: *jerk or jolt (someone or something) suddenly, typically so as to cause injury*.

Whiplash is referring to a time when something changes suddenly (in the case of a car accident, your head jerks suddenly in another direction).

When the author says "We are in a whiplash moment right now" they mean that we are living in a time where the US relations with Russia had suddenly changed (or jerked in another direction).  Under the current/old administration of the US, Russian-US relations were relatively rocky, however with Donald Trump it seems they'll be much friendlier.

In short, a whiplash is used in this case to describe a sudden change.  The article is referring to the whiplash moment we are living in as the period of this change.